# Call livewire component from button in external component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am testing Livewire and would like to do the following:

From a component, which has a button, call from there to my livewire component to display an iframe with the path provided by the button but I can't get it to make the call.

My component have the following code (`/resources/views/components/widgets/lista-plantillas.blade.php`):

```
<div class="card-group">
@foreach ($plantillas as $plantilla)
    <div class="card" wire:key="plantilla-{{ $plantilla->id }}">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">{!! $plantilla->nombre !!}</h6>
            <small class="card-body">Creada el: {{ $plantilla->created_at }}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            {{-- <input @click="$wire.dispatch('carga-event')" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="plantilla" id="success-outlined-{{$plantilla->id}}" autocomplete="off" value="{{$plantilla->id}}"> --}}
            <input type="radio" 
                   class="btn-check" 
                   name="plantilla" 
                   id="success-outlined-{{ $plantilla->id }}"
                   autocomplete="off" 
                   value="{{$plantilla->id}}"
                   @click="$wire.dispatch('carga-event', {id: {{ $plantilla->id }} })"
            />
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined-{{$plantilla->id}}">¡Usar para email!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And the principal file (`/resources/views/crea-comunicado.blade.php`) have the code:

```
 <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#extraComunicado" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="extraComunicado">
                                <span class="badge bg-primary">3</span>&nbsp;Adjuntos y programaci&oacute;n
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="extraComunicado" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accionesComunicado">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                               <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3">
                                        <label for="adjuntos" class="form-label">Adjuntar ficheros:</label>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="adjuntos" name="adjuntos" multiple />
                                    </div>                                    
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3" id="programaEnvio">
                                        <label for="programado" class="form-label">Programar env&iacute;o: </label>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <label class="input-group-text" for="programado"><i class="bi bi-alarm-fill"></i></label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="programado" id="programado" multiple="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                    
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#previaComunicado" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="previaComunicado">
                                <span class="badge bg-success">5</span>&nbsp;Vista Previa
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="previaComunicado" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accionesComunicado">
                            <div class="container">
                                
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">
                                            <div id="datos-adjuntos">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary position-relative" style="cursor:inherit">
                                                    Ficheros adjuntos
                                                    <span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill" id="numero-adjuntos"> </span>
                                                </button>
                                                <ul class="list-group m-2" id="listado-adjuntos"></ul>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-light" id="programado-mail"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="sacacontenido"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 ">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">
                                            <small id="previa-asunto"></small>
                                            <livewire:previa-plantilla />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

And my liveware view (`/resources/views/livewire`) is just a test like:

```
<div>    
    <p>Mira donde estoy</p>    
    {{ $url_file }}
</div>
```

And my liveware component (`/app/Livewire/PreviaPlantilla.php`) is:

```
use App\Models\Plantilla;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class PreviaPlantilla extends Component
{
    public $count=0;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.previa-plantilla');
    }

    #[On("carga-event")]

    public function carga(){        
        $this->count++;
    }

}
```

**Change thanks to @Pippo explanation ;)**

I change my laravel component into livewire component and it looks like that now:

```
class PreviaPlantilla extends Component
{
    public $count;
    public $id;
    public $plantilla;
    public $content;
    public $dataHTML;
    public $rutaPlantilla;

    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.previa-plantilla');
    }

    #[On("carga-event")]
    public function carga($id){
        
        $this->plantilla = Plantilla::where("id",$id)->first();
        $this->rutaPlantilla = $this->plantilla->ruta_html;
        $this->dataHTML = File::get("storage/plantillas/".$this->rutaPlantilla);
        $this->count++;
    }

}
```

But now, I need to use a value that is in an input, but I don't know how to send it to my livewire because the value can change.

My input is before use the livewires components and looks like that (it's use tinymce):

```
<form method="post"> 
  <textarea id="myeditorinstance">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the button?

Comment: Is a radio-button...the idea is: that button will give to me a ID that I will use to search a url value into my database...and it will change me a iframe. But at the moment, I only want to make the change in my strinig.

Answer (score 0):

To let interact two components placed on the same page you can use events.
The "button" from the *lista-plantillas* view can send an event that is managed by the *PreviaPlantilla* class

To save a call to the backend, in my example, the event is sent directly from the frontend:

**lista-plantillas.blade.php**

```html
<div class="card-group">

    @foreach ($plantillas as $plantilla)

        <div class="card" wire:key="plantilla-{{ $plantilla->id }}">

            <div class="card-footer text-muted">

                <input type="radio" 
                       class="btn-check" 
                       name="plantilla" 
                       id="success-outlined-{{ $plantilla->id }}"
                       autocomplete="off" 
                       value="{{$plantilla->id}}"
                       @click="$wire.dispatch('carga-event', {id: {{ $plantilla->id }} })"
                >
                <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined-{{$plantilla->id}}">¡Usar para email!</label>

            </div>

        </div>

    @endforeach

</div>
```

**class PreviaPlantilla**

```php
use Livewire\Attributes\On;  // <--- NOTE THIS
use Livewire\Component;

class PreviaPlantilla extends Component
{
    public $url_file="testfile";


    #[On("carga-event")]
    public function carga($id) {
        $this->url_file = "I will use [$id] to load some data";
    }
}
```

The `@click="$wire.dispatch('carga-event', {id: {{ $plantilla->id }} })"`
in the view send the event *carga-event* with the parameter *id* from the frontend, note also the *wire:key* added in the main div into the @foreach (it's needed to avoid conflicts in case of refresh of the rows)

In the *PreviaPlantilla* class the *carga* method is triggered by the event (specified by the attribute #[On()]), here you can use also the dependency injection e.g. using a model as parameter

I'm not entirely convinced that a radio button is the best solution for this scenario, but since I can't see the situation in its entirety, I can't give an exact opinion

### Changes after some explanations

Since *lista-plantillas.blade.php* is not a livewire component, we can't use any "wire:" directive.
We can try to use some Alpine code to dispatch the event:

```html
<div class="card-group" x-data>

    @foreach ($plantillas as $plantilla)

        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-footer text-muted">

                <input type="radio" 
                       class="btn-check" 
                       name="plantilla" 
                       id="success-outlined-{{ $plantilla->id }}"
                       autocomplete="off" 
                       value="{{$plantilla->id}}"
                       @click="$dispatch('carga-event', {id: {{ $plantilla->id }} })"
                >
                <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined-{{$plantilla->id}}">¡Usar para email!</label>

            </div>

        </div>

    @endforeach

</div>
```

It works if *Liwewire* / *Alpine*  are already loaded when the view-component is rendered (note the *x-data* in the main *<div>*)

Otherwise we can simply send the event with vanilla JS (*x-data* is not needed):

```html
<input type="radio" 
       ....
       value="{{$plantilla->id}}"
       onclick="window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('carga-event', { detail: {id: {{ $plantilla->id }} } }))"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for de answer @Pippo but isn't works yet...I will edit te main question, maybe you will be the idea clearer and better the code. I'm using 3 files the principal view and two (normal component and "livewire" component) an the normal one is trying to give some values to the livewire component.

Comment: A non-Livewire component can't use *"wire:"* directives. Do you confirm that  *lista-plantillas* is a classic blade component? If so we can try to trigger the event via AlpineJs or even in vanilla JS

Comment: Thanks for your help @Pippo! I will try to make it with AlpineJS but I'm a little lost with that too.  How can make the call to my livewire with AlipneJS?

Comment: Alpine is already included in Livewire 3, so depending on how the page is composed (scripts inclusion, etc.) it may or may not already be loaded when the component is rendered. If it doesn't work you can try the vanilla version, the result is the same. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I edited my answer and added the information for Alpine and for vanilla JS

Comment: I'm just thinking @Pippo... If I can change my laravel component to livewire component...can I send datas between both of them??

Comment: Yes, you can do so, in that case the first part of my answer is valid. For simplicity, however, I recommend you try with Alpine or javascript events

Comment: Thanks again @Pippo! I will change the code into my question to update that...because...I will need help to pass other attribute and change his value with javascript

Comment: Very well. However, it is not good practice to constantly change the question. Usually if you are satisfied with an answer you can accept it, otherwise not. A new question with additional requirements may subsequently be submitted